# 'Area' and 'Perimeter' dimension - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Is there a way to convert the regionprops 'Area' and 'Perimeter' parameters to real dimension? I have the x1, y1 and x2, y2 of a scale bar so I used the code below to have the size factor hoping that simple multiplication it by the 'Area' and 'Perimeter' regionprop result but it does not work? Is it possible? Any idea?

Code:

```
distS = sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2);
scaleValue = 10; %in cm
sizeFactor = scaleValue/distS;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works.

Perimeter is a length (cm) so multiplying the perimeter in pixels by `sizeFactor` gives the perimeter in cm.

Area is a square length (cm²) so you need to multiply twice by `sizeFactor` to get area in cm² (that is, `area*sizeFactor*sizeFactor`).

These conversions hold true for any length and area measurements. A length measured in pixels is multiplied by the conversion factor, and an area measured in square pixels is multiplied by the square of the conversion factor. You can tell this is correct by paying attention to the units:

`area_px` pixels² `*` `factor` cm²/pixels² = `area_cm` cm²

Comment: Just to verify, can it be also used for 'ConvexArea' and 'EquivDiameter'?

Comment: @jane: Yes. The first is an area, the second a length. Use the right conversion for each. See the edited answer.